# Scraping with DOMDocument PHP

Tags: php

This is the current code that I have for scraping.

$item is the HTML for the div HTML within the loop.

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($item);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$link = "//a[@class='s-item__link']";
$entries = $xpath->query($link);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    // do work here
}
```

I am changing the first two lines to be...

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$xpath = $doc->load($item);
```

With that, I am getting the following error...

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on bool in

The error is coming in from `$entries = $xpath->query($link);` and I can not figure out where to change this line to.

### Update

Same error

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$xpath = $doc->loadHTML($item);
$link = "//a[@class='s-item__link']";
$entries = $xpath->query($link);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    // do work here
}
```

Comment: `$doc->loadHTML()` doesnt return XPath so query wont be there, you need this instead `$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);`

Comment: Hey hey, did you ever solve your problem?  Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the return value from [`DOMDocument:load()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php)...

> Returns true on success or false on failure. ***If called statically***, returns a DOMDocument or false on failure.

Emphasis: Mine.  Notice that you're not calling it statically anymore with your change.

So, with code like, `$xpath = $doc->load($item);`, of course `$xpath` will need to be a bool (true or false), and your error makes total sense: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on bool`.

I just scooped out the Xpath stuff I'm using right now for my own PHP scraper.  This should work...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($htmltext, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
```

Explanation:

- `new DOMDocument` : New class instance of `DOMDocument()`.
- `@$dom->loadHTML` : The `@` symbol suppresses warnings, and this class is very wordy with its errors, you don't want to see them all the time.
- `mb_convert_encoding($htmltext, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8')` : `loadHTML()` appreciates properly UTF-8 encoded text, also, `mb_convert_encoding()` is optimized for massive strings.
- `new DOMXPath($dom);` : New class instance of `DOMXPath()`.

Answer (score 0):

`->load` expects a `filename` as first parameter as shown in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php).

In your first code block, you use `loadHTML`.

Use `->loadHTML` instead off `->load` on an empty `DomDocument`:

```php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$xpath = $doc->loadHTML($item);
```

---

```
public load ( string $filename , int $options = 0 )         : DOMDocument|bool
public loadHTML ( string $source , int $options = 0 )       : DOMDocument|bool
public loadHTMLFile ( string $filename , int $options = 0 ) : DOMDocument|bool
```

Comment: This produced the same error for me. I added the updated code to my question.

Comment: Please share the content of `$item`